# Is distributor not needed in Azure setup?

Tags: nservicebus

I read somewhere that a Distributor is needed when the queues are local on specific servers an you want to scale out. 
I want to use nServiceBus on Azure with Azure ServiceBus. The Azure ServiceBus is shared. 
Do I understand correctly that I can just fire up multiple workers on same or multiple worker roles with no distributor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked Yves Goeleven (responsible for much of the NServiceBus on Azure implementation) this exact question a few weeks ago and the answer is no, a distributor is not necessary when running on Azure. You can point multiple workers at the same queue.

Comment: Great :-)  Good to know I am not a complete moron when it comes to understanding nServiceBus.

Comment: Ben,  I am interested to know more about this aspect and can't quite wrap my head around the specifics, as we are moving to scaling out our stuff in Azure.  On premise scale out could be achieved using distributors and workers.  How do we ensure only one worker deals with a message and there isn't contention on the message? I think this is called competing consumer. Is peek-lock leveraged here?